# Why is the first item moving to the left when I put the mouse over it?

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming and I wanted to make a navbar where a name is on the left of the navbar and the other navigation items are on the right. I put  `transfer:scale()` effect on the items and all of them on the right side are working good, but the one on the left is moving to the left when the animation is happening. Pls help me how to fix it, so the navigation is not stretched to the left so it works like on the right side.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

nav a {
  line-height: 19px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style";
  padding: 0px 14px 0 14px;
}

nav a:not(#logo) {
  text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #b3d0ff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="logo" style="flex:1" href="index.html">Hidden Logo</a>
  <a href="en.html">EN</a>
  <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#portfolioo">PORTFOLIO</a>
  <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
</nav>
```

Sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale):

> The scale() CSS function defines a transformation that resizes an element on the 2D plane. Because the amount of scaling is defined by a vector, it can resize the horizontal and vertical dimensions at different scales. Its result is a  data type.

With this said, you have `flex: 1;` on the first child meaning the amount of scaling is increased because of the horizontal dimensions at different scales.

**Solution:**

Remove `flex: 1;` and use `margin-left: auto;` on the second `a` as an alternative.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

nav a {
  line-height: 19px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style";
  padding: 0px 14px 0 14px;
}

nav a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

nav a:not(#logo) {
  text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #b3d0ff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="logo" href="index.html">Hidden Logo</a>
  <a href="en.html">EN</a>
  <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#portfolioo">PORTFOLIO</a>
  <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `flex` it made the item long so the side of it went to the left when scaling. My solution was to use `float` instead of `flex`.

```css
nav {

  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
  
}

nav a {
  line-height: 19px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style";
  padding: 0px 14px 0 14px;
  float: right;
}

nav a:not(#logo) {
  text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #b3d0ff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="logo" style="float:left; " href="index.html">Hidden Logo</a>
  <a href="en.html">EN</a>
<!--
  <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#portfolioo">PORTFOLIO</a>
  <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
-->
  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
</nav>
after
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
nav a:not(#logo) {
  text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #b3d0ff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

To:

```
#logo {
    text-align: left;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #b3d0ff;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

With `transform` you are moving the logo. I think with transition and font-size you can have what you want. I hope it helps